# Stabilizing serial device names across reboots for serial console

Tags: udev, tty, serial-port, serial-console

I have an embedded Linux system with 2 built-in serial ports, and a PCI board that adds 8 more.

The kernel enumerates the devices in a way that the port numbers end up getting interleaved, for instance (from `dmesg`):

```
[    5.964467] 0000:03:00.0: ttyS4 at MMIO 0xd0600000 (irq = 105, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    5.964934] 0000:03:00.0: ttyS5 at MMIO 0xd0600400 (irq = 105, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    5.965213] 0000:03:00.0: ttyS6 at MMIO 0xd0600800 (irq = 105, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    5.965519] 0000:03:00.0: ttyS7 at MMIO 0xd0600c00 (irq = 105, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    5.965879] 0000:03:00.0: ttyS8 at MMIO 0xd0601000 (irq = 105, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    5.966755] 0000:00:1e.3: ttyS9 at MMIO 0xd091c000 (irq = 18, base_baud = 2764800) is a 16550A
[    5.967123] 0000:03:00.0: ttyS10 at MMIO 0xd0601400 (irq = 105, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    5.967411] 0000:03:00.0: ttyS11 at MMIO 0xd0601800 (irq = 105, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    5.967705] 0000:03:00.0: ttyS12 at MMIO 0xd0601c00 (irq = 105, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    5.976690] 0000:00:1e.4: ttyS13 at MMIO 0xd091a000 (irq = 19, base_baud = 2764800) is a 16550A
```

Here the built-in ports got assigned the names `ttyS9` and `ttyS13` and the expansion ports got `ttyS4-8` and `ttyS10-12`. On the next reboot, the assignment will vary.

Because the port names get shuffled around, I don't have a stable identifier for my kernel command line option `console=ttyS4,115200` or for `getty`.

I can write `udev` rules that create stable symlinks which might work for `getty` but don't work for the kernel's command line.

I have tried using the MMIO address for the Linux command line, as in `console=uart,mmio32,0xd091c000,115200` and while the system boots, I don't seem to be receiving any kernel output.

How can I stabilize these identifiers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if you haven't tried already, perhaps try changing the biosdevname=0|1 argument for the kernel ?

Its value is usually changed in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX prior to running grub2-mkconfig on pc's, that part may well be different in your embedded situation ofcourse.

Comment: Is this option specifically for network interface devices? It doesn't seem to apply (and I checked the kernel sources and it is not documented and doesn't appear in the Linux source).

Comment: I'm not sure. Network interface naming is indeed the thing i have used it for in the past, and likely what most people use it for; but the name isn't particularly network-specific so flipping that would have been my first attempt in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

My partial *workaround* (not an ideal solution) is to have a udev helper script that looks at the kernel's device name, e.g., `ttyS5`, and looks up the device's place in the PCI device tree by resolving the symlink `/sys/class/tty/ttyS5`. Then it looks at all other TTY devices on the same node, and takes the *index* of this device amongst its peers. The assumption is that the order of devices within this node is stable, even if the device names are not.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import os


# Parse arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("kernel_dev")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Find peer devices of this one
sysfspath = os.path.realpath(f"/sys/class/tty/{args.kernel_dev}")
peer_devices = os.listdir(os.path.dirname(sysfspath))
peer_devices.sort(key=lambda d: (len(d), d))  # natural sort

# Print the index of this device among its peers
print(peer_devices.index(args.kernel_dev) + 1)
```

The udev rule then becomes:

```
... PROGRAM="/usr/bin/serial_device_index %k", SYMLINK+="ttyEXP%c" ...
```

This solution may need to be tweaked for other hardware configurations.

### What I don't like

This just makes stable symlink names, it doesn't make stable names which might be useful for things like assigning a device to the kernel's `console` parameter, or using Ubuntu's `getty` login console systemd services.

Comment: Actually, stable symlink names are the preferred method to deal with this - it's the same principle udev uses for event layer input devices, harddisks, etc. And use `udevadm` to have a look at the attributes provided inside `udev` (which ultimately come from `/sys`), you may be able to do this with a simple rule instead of a script.